# Wicket Application Structure Best Practice

Tags: wicket

I am working with an application that has some Wicket pages, divided into some Applications. We are expanding the Wicket development to substitute other legacy content. Right now, there is no clear path wether to write new Wicket Applications for each workflow, or if we should have one big Application with many URL mappings. I did not find any information about this either.

As far as we are, we see following issues:

Many Wicket Applications pattern:

- Each Application (Workflow) can be easily mounted without much of a hassle.
- Even if it's not more time consuming, you end up writing more Java Classes (at least for each Application you need at least some basic structure).
- Each Application default URL get's accessed by it's homepage, so no further config is necessary.

One big Application pattern:

- Each Workflow needs a Page, which has to be mapped in the Application class. As far as I've seen, there is no configuration in xml files to archieve this, but it should be possible to develop some schema that allows to structure this in some xml file. Disatvantage: more time consuming for the first time
- For further addings, it should be somewhat easier than with the Application pattern, but it doesn't make a difference that would make a real difference considering that the workflow development is always way bigger than the initial config.
- Each Workflow default URL can be accessed by the URL mapping, and can be changed easily, it seems a little easier than with the Application approach, but doesn't make a big difference either.

Now, what I'm looking for:

- Opinion based on experiences, maybe arguments for deciding for one or another way.
- Is there any documentation from Apache or some source for this? If so, some reference would be a great advice.

Comment: May be it's not important in your scenario, but for me there is one important diference, at the one big application all the workflows share the same user session (this is important if you have user authentication), while if you split in several applications each workflow has a different session.

Comment: Mmm, just to be clear, I mean different Wicket Applications in one Web Module, so they will still share the session... You just define each application in your WEB.xml, but all are on the same WebContainer. So it's really not a matter of session scope or similar thoughts, it's more a question of how's the best way to organize a big application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand it, you would still deploy all of your Wicket Applications within one single Web Archive.

Doing that, in my opinion you lose the only real advantage of separating your code into different Wicket Applications. If you separate your code into **multiple Wicket Application** classes

- you have to think of configuring each Wicket Application the same way and not forget a single one (include it in the web.xml, call the same settings in the init()-method, ...)
- you are writing more boilerplate code as you already said yourself

The configuration and code would be more complex than with the "single application" approach. With a **single application**

- you only have to mount the start page of each workflow in your single application class...which is one line of code compared to a new class and some lines of web.xml config with the multiple applications approac

So, if you don't want to deploy your workflows separately, I'd go with a single application. It makes it so much easier. Especially when you have accumulated more than a couple workflows the single application approach will probably be much easier to maintain.

Comment: OK, seems fair enough. They will be indeed together, maybe in different maven modules, but that's another story that can be controlled anyway. I was looking for such an answer in the Apache Wicket Site. Now, I was considering the different application approach as I didn't find a way to configure url mappings in an xml file (without implementing it at least). Have you done url mappings per configuration rather tan in the Application class?

Comment: I have not tried XML configuration for page flows in Wicket yet, since I really like doing it programmatically. However it probably makes sense in you case since you are explicitly modelling workflows. There is an integration of Wicket and Spring Web Flow at https://github.com/wicketstuff/core/tree/core-1.4.x/jdk-1.5-parent/spring-webflow-parent but it has not been maintained for 2 years...probably won't work with the current Wicket without changes. Other than that, you could create your own XML configuration mechanism to model your workflows. Or even your own integration with Spring Webflow.

Answer (score 0):

- How much shared coda are you likely to have?
- Are there different performance/load tolerance/availability requirements for the different workflows?

These are the questions I use in general to decide whether two things should go in one application or not, and that's pretty much independent from Wicket.

Obviously much shared code points towards a single application. Of course you can still use separate applications with all of them depending on a set of shared modules but in practice you'll spend a lot of time trying to keep your modules in sync.

Similarly, wildly different availability requirements might steer you in the direction of separate applications as you'd probably want to deploy them separately.

The most difficult scenario is if you have much shared code AND you still want to deploy them separately, in that case a multi-tiered approach (multiple frontends connecting to a common backend) might be worth considering.